# How to configure Wireguard client running on a server to maintain remote access to server?

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

I have a server running a few web apps that I wish to remain accessible to the public. I also want to use the Wireguard client on the server. However, enabling Wireguard prevents me from accessing the server via SSH, and the web apps stop working.

How can I use Wireguard whilst maintaining remote access to the server?

The client config on the server is as follows:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = XXX
Address = 10.66.66.3/32,fd42:42:42::3/128
DNS = 94.140.14.14,94.140.15.15

[Peer]
PublicKey = XXX
PresharedKey = XXX
Endpoint = XXX
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Set `Table=` (and `FwMark=`) explicitly and customize the policy routing yourself (probably you'll need to configure additional {ct,meta} mark; or if there are only a few simple services that need to be exempted, matching with source port would probably work as well).

Comment: Or if the VPN is not for Internet access but merely certain "site" access, avoid `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` (but add only the necessary IP blocks to the list).